# Did here existed a better solution to handle this api problem in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, algorithm, uitableview

my raw json data maybe mislead you. The keys array were not always matched its value at the same index. So I rewrote my data to reflect my intentions.

Assume we have a table view to show songs with its json:

```
{
    "albums": [
        {
            "title": "A",
            "id": "174172",
            "artistName": "Person X"
        },
        {
            "title": "B",
            "id": "19201827",
            "artistName": "Person Y"
        },
        {
            "title": "C",
            "id": "1927",
            "artistName": "Person Z"
        }
    ],
    "songs": [
        {
            "name": "Song A",
            "albumName": "A",
            "albumId": "174172",
            "duration": 180
        },
        {
            "name": "Song B",
            "albumName": "A",
            "albumId": "174172",
            "duration": 200
        },
        {
            "name": "Song C",
            "albumName": "B",
            "albumId": "19201827",
            "duration": 216
        },
        {
            "name": "Song D",
            "albumName": "C",
            "albumId": "1927",
            "duration": 216
        }
    ]
}
```

My schemas like this:

```
struct Album: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let id: String
    let artistName: String
}

struct Song: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let albumName: String
    let albumId: String
    let duration: Int
}
```

The view controller fake code like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var songs: [Song] = []
    var albums: [Album] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongCell", for: indexPath) as! SongCell
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        let album = albums.first { $0.id == song.albumId }
        cell.updateUI(withSong: song, album: album)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        let album = albums.first { $0.id == song.albumId }
        pushDetailSongViewController(song, album)
    }

    func pushDetailSongViewController(_ song: Song, _ album: Album?) {
    }
}
```

When we have too many songs with albums, `let album = albums.first { $0.id == song.albumId }` is place with terrible performance problem.

So what data structure should we use here to handle updateing performance?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thanks for your answer. I thought my raw question may mislead and I update all json now. Would you to read it again?

Comment: I updated my answer. It's exactly the same like before, except I had to rename a couple of fields. Note, however, that this will only match one song per album. You'd have to do `[Album: [Song]]`, to get a dictionary of albums and all songs that belong to each album.

Comment: So, I've also added the `[Album: [Song]]` functionality to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing both keys and values, you could combine the two arrays to a dictionary and then have your table view's data source be that dictionary.

First, make your `Song` struct conform to the `Hashable` protocol:

```
struct Song: Hashable {
```

Create an array for both albums and songs:

```
var albums: [Album] = []
var songs:  [Song]  = []
```

Then, reduce the `songs` array to a dictionary as follows:

```
let data = songs.reduce([Album: Song]()) { (result, song) -> [Album: Song] in
    guard let album = albums.first(where: { $0.id == song.albumID }) else { return result }
    return result.merging([album: song], uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })
}
```

---

I tested this with two demo arrays:

```
let albums = [Album(id: "1",     name: "one"), Album(id: "2",     name: "two"), Album(id: "3",     name: "three")]
let songs  = [Song(albumID: "1", name: "ONE"), Song(albumID: "2", name: "TWO"), Song(albumID: "3", name: "THREE")]
```

Those turn `data` into:

```
[
    <Album id: "1", name: "one">  : <Song albumID: "1", name: "ONE">,
    <Album id: "2", name: "two">  : <Song albumID: "2", name: "TWO">,
    <Album id: "3", name: "three">: <Song albumID: "3", name: "THREE">
]
```

---

#### Extra Credit

If you want all songs for each album, you have to make `data` `[Album: [Song]]`:

```
let data = albums.reduce([Album: [Song]]()) { (result, album) -> [Album: [Song]] in
    let _songs = songs.filter({ $0.albumID == album.id })
    guard !_songs.isEmpty else { return result }
    return result.merging([album: _songs], uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })
}
```

With the following arrays:

```
let albums = [Album(id: "1",     name: "one"), Album(id: "2",     name: "two"), Album(id: "3",     name: "three")]
let songs  = [Song(albumID: "1", name: "ONE"), Song(albumID: "2", name: "TWO"), Song(albumID: "3", name: "THREE"),
              Song(albumID: "1", name: "ONE-1"), Song(albumID: "1", name: "ONE-2"), Song(albumID: "3", name: "THREE-1")]
```

...you will get:

```
[
    <Album name: three, id: 3>: [
        <Song name: THREE, albumID: 3>
        <Song name: THREE-1, albumID: 3>
    ], 
    <Album name: one, id: 1>: [
        <Song name: ONE, albumID: 1>, 
        <Song name: ONE-1, albumID: 1>, 
        <Song name: ONE-2, albumID: 1>
    ],
    <Album name: two, id: 2>: [
        <Song name: TWO, albumID: 2>
    ]
]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `struct` like below after the `JSON` parsing has been completed.

```
struct DataSet {
 let id: String
 let name: String
 let value: String
}
```

Moreover looking at your json, it seems like objects at same index of `Key` and `Value` arrays are same with respect to `id` and `key` . So, at the time of combining both the arrays, if you iterate one array, you will be knowing the index of another array (`O(1)`) . Hence time complexity of merging will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought my raw question may mislead and I update all json now. Would you to read it again?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change too much, maybe a mapDictionary will help:

```
    let keyMaps =  [String : String](uniqueKeysWithValues: keys.map{($0.id, $0.name)})
    keyNamesInSequenceSameWithValues =  values.map{ keyMaps[$0.key]! )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought my raw question may mislead and I update all json now. Would you to read it again?